# How to update a component using AlarmManager?

Tags: java, android, web-services, android-asynctask, alarmmanager

I'm working in an application that needs to do a background job every 5 seconds to retrieve an image from a server, when the job is done, the `ImageView` in my UI needs to be updated if there is something in return.
I'm using `AlarmManager` to do the job but don't know how to update the UI when the job is done.
Also I want to know if this is the best way to do it, or if I have to implement some kind of service.

This is my `onCreate` method, where I initialize my UI components and the `AlarmManager` with the `PendingIntent`:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    swtSIGNAL = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.swtSIGNAL);
    snackView = swtSIGNAL;
    swtSIGNAL.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if (!isChecked) {
                mSetSignalTask = new SetSignalAsync(progressDialog, snackView, true);
                mSetSignalTask.execute();
            } else {
                mSetSignalTask = new SetSignalAsync(progressDialog, snackView, false);
                mSetSignalTask.execute();
            }
        }
    });

    swtALARM=(Switch)findViewById(R.id.swtALARM);
    snackView=swtALARM;
    swtALARM.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if (!isChecked) {
                mSetAlarmTask = new SetAlarmAsync(progressDialog, snackView,true);
                mSetAlarmTask.execute();
            } else {
                mSetAlarmTask = new SetAlarmAsync(progressDialog,snackView,false);
                mSetAlarmTask.execute();
            }
        }
    });

    imgFOTO=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgFOTO);

    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
    progressDialog.isIndeterminate();

    callListener = new EndCallListener();
    telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    telephonyManager.listen(callListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);

    Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);
    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, alarmIntent, 0);
}
```

This is my `setAlarm` method which activates the AlarmManager:

```
public void setAlarm(){
    manager=(AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    int interval=5000;

    manager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,System.currentTimeMillis(),interval,pendingIntent);
    Toast.makeText(this, "Alarm Set", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

This is the `AlarmReceiver` class which extends from a `BroadcastReceiver`:

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Working", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Finally this is the method that fetches the image from the server; I'm using `AsyncTask` to not freeze the app.

```
public class GetImageAsync extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Bitmap>{

    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try{
                URL url=new URL("http://192.168.0.16/HouseSecure/SECImages/example.jpg");
                HttpURLConnection connection=(HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
                connection.setDoInput(true);
                connection.connect();
                InputStream inputStream=connection.getInputStream();
                Bitmap image= BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
                connection.disconnect();
                return image;
        }catch (MalformedURLException e){
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, e.getMessage());
            return null;
        }catch(IOException ex){
            Log.e(LOG_TAG,ex.getMessage());
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap image) {
        imgFOTO.setImageBitmap(image);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it your AlarmReceiver that starts the GetImageAsync task? Did you just forget to include that line in your AlarmReceiver class above?

Answer (score 0):

Use AlarmClock API Provided by Studio instead of AlarmManager if you are going to set an Alarm